# Mostrar u ocultar (contraer o desplegar ) código en Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Quiero saber si existe algun plugin o atajo el cual permita de contraer el codigo en sublime, ya que aveces necesito ocultar mucho codigo y es tedioso hacerlo con el mouse uno a uno

pasar de esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he buscado en los atajos, pero no encontré nada relacionado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo sin plugin,
Si seleccionas las lineas que quieres contraer y vas a Edit menu --->Code Folding --> Fold te lo hace.
Si no tambien hay un plugin si quieres
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Base64%20Fold

Comment: Gracias! justamente era eso lo que buscaba